# where can I find mysql_install_db for Mac

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I have downloaded mysql-advanced-5.1.46sp1-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg and installed it. I have a custom my.cnf file and no data to begin with. I dont see mysql_install_db any where. How can i  install one. The server where I am copying this configuration from has mysql_install_db present. pkginfo returns nothing useful and man page states that this mysql_install_db is from Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to README, MySQL.pkg gets installed into `/usr/local/mysql-VERSION`

mysql_install_db is located in `/usr/local/mysql-VERSION/scripts/`

> The Mac OS X PKG of MySQL installs itself into
>   `/usr/local/mysql-VERSION' and also installs a symbolic link,`
>   /usr/local/mysql', that points to the new location. If a directory
>   named `/usr/local/mysql' exists, it is renamed to`
>   /usr/local/mysql.bak' first. Additionally, the installer creates the
>   grant tables in the `mysql' database by executing`mysql_install_db'.